# Extending a lemma about Castelnuovo-Mumford regularity

Tags: commutative-algebra, graded-modules, graded-rings

I'm learning Castelnuovo-Mumford regularity of associated graded ring. There is a lemma:

[image]
[image]
[image]

It's from ["Castelnuovo-Mumford regularity postulation number and relation types"](https://www.math.uzh.ch/fileadmin/user/brodmann/publikation/BLi_REGREL_May13_2014.pdf) by Markus Brodmann and Cao Huy Linh.

Now, I want to extend it to modules.

**Lemma 3.3**. Let $(A,\mathfrak{m})$ be a Noetherian local ring of dimension one. $M$ is an $A$-module with $\operatorname{dim} M=1$, $I=(x)$ is a submodule of $M$. Then

$$\operatorname{reg}(G_I(M))=p(G_I(M))+\operatorname{depth}(A).$$

In proof, I also replace from above proof: $\operatorname{depth}(A)$ to $\operatorname{depth}(M)$, $\mathfrak{q}$ to $I$, $L:=H^0_{\mathfrak{m}}(M)$,...

So, please show me wrong point in new proof. Please do it with more detail. 
Thank so much!

Comment: Shouldn't $I$ be an *ideal* of $A$ and a parameter ideal for $M$? Furthermore, I think you should have shown your own tries and where exactly have doubts.

Comment: I find my question pretty clear: you can't form the associated graded module $G_I(M)$ if $I$ is not an ideal. Moreover, in Lemma 3.3, $\mathfrak q$ is a parameter ideal, while in your generalization to modules there is no ideal and no condition.

Comment: So if i fix it to: $I=(x)$ with $x$ is $M$-regular, is it ok? And please show me about $L$ anđ $H_I(n-1)$ or anything need fix! THanks

Comment: I've told you in my first comment as $I$ should be. I don't understand what do you want to know about $L$ (which must be exactly what you said in your first comment) and even less about $H_I(n-1)$.

Comment: Yes, i mean that: is it right if i change $L=H^0_{\mathfrak{m}}(A)$ to $L=H^0_{\mathfrak{m}}(M)$? With $H_I(n-1)$, i'm not sure about equations when change from ring to modules.

Comment: I think $L$ should be $H^0_{\mathfrak m}(M)$. At least then you are sure that $x$ is $M/L$-regular. I'd say that nothing wrong can happen when switch that equations to modules.